# How to find which record a specific piece of data is in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, record

I am writing a programme for my class where I must take get input data from a user and put that data into a record which in turn goes into an array.

```
def createArray0fRecords(length):
  city_records = ["", "", 0.0,""]#Create record
  #City, Country, Population in Millions, Main Language

  city_array = [city_records]*length #Create Array of Records

  return city_array

def populateRecords(city_array):
  for counter in range (0, len(city_array)):
      print("")
      print("Please enter the city")
      city=input()

      print('Please enter the country')
      country=input()

      print("Please enter the population in millions")
      population=float(input())
      while population < 0:
        print(population," isn't a valid answer. Please input a number greater than 0.")
        population=input()
      print("Please enter the main language")
      language = input()

      city_array[counter] = [city, country, population, language]

  return city_array

def main_program():
  print("How many cities will you be entering?")
  length = int(input())
  city_array = createArray0fRecords(length)
  city_array = populateRecords(city_array)
  print("What city would you like the information about?")
  city=input()
  if city in (city_array[1]):
    print(city_array[city])

main_program()
```

I believe I am almost there and it is just the las few lines that must now be changed. Thanks

Sorry, I am new to stack overflow and I have realised I worded my question wrong, what I must do is Take all of the information in, then I must input what city I would like to get the information about and the program will give me the information about that city

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the actual question here? What specifically is supposed to happen when you run the program, and how is that different from what actually happens?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack overflow and I have realised I worded my question wrong, what I must do is Take all of the information in, then I must input what city I would like to get the information about and the program will give me the information about that city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter city_array by the relevant city name like so ([you can read on list comprehensions here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

```
relevant_cities = [c for c in city_array if c[0] == city]
```

relevant_cities will now be an list of all records having city equal to the user's input. You can now check if this list is empty and do whatever you'd like with it.

Comment: Thank you! So is this the way to do it and it is simply putting this line of code into my program or is there still more to do?

Comment: There are more ways to do it, but essentially it is enough to put this line into your program instead of "if city in (city_array[1]): ...". After this line you can write print(relevant_cities[0]) to get the first element which is relevant. But be careful, an error will be thrown if no relevant city is found.

Comment: Perfect mate, ty